# Circuit to turn relay on/off based on button press

Tags: switches, relay

I'm using a CPU case to enclose a diy project and I'm looking to see if I can turn the main circuits power supply on using the on/off switch in the front panel of the case. The button needs a circuit that would trigger a relay on/off based on the button press. What would be the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: If you're more handy with mechanics than electronics replacing the switch with a push-push switch might be easier than messing with circuitry.

Comment: thanks for the comment @SpehroPefhany. good suggestion. but for my learning still would like to know a circuit design for this problem.

Comment: You may use push button with latch, sliding switch, rocker switch, toggle switch, etc.

Comment: What's the type of power supply that you intend to use?

Comment: There is a common press-on/press-off circuit used in many products. It has been on stackexchange before, likely a number of times. You can even add a relay after the power mosfet if you need isolation or more drive current. I'm not taking credit for it, (see the circuit using 2 mosfets), here it is:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283255/momentary-to-latching-circuit-with-zero-off-current

Comment: thanks all, i found a module on the internet that does exactly what i want. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004355529341.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple 5V circuit. You can add a logic-level MOSFET or a BJT + base resistor and a flyback diode to drive a relay. Gates can be 74HC00.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj0lJX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I recommend you replace D1 and C1 with ADM809 or equivalent for more reliable power-on reset to 'off' (or 'on' if you connect to the opposite gate).

R3 is optional but it tends to reduce clucking noises from the peanut gallery.